# Clipping images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image-processing, clip

So far I haven't found anything to substitute using the clip property. I've tried sing negative margins to no avail. And now my last hope is javascript. I've googled it but haven't really found what I'm looking for.

What I want is to clip the edges of pictures, so when the blur filter is applied to an image, the edges aren't blurred but are crisp. Yes I did use svg filters but couldn't find a proper way to make the transition smooth

```
<style>
#content{
background:#fff;
}

.one{
width:455px;
height:213px;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}

.one img{
position:relative;
top:-30px;
left:-7px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.one img:hover{
filter: blur(3px); -webkit-filter: blur(3px); -moz-filter: blur(3px);
-o-filter: blur(3px); -ms-filter: blur(3px);
filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
</style>

<div id="content">

<span class="one">
<a href="/"><img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/create/1/0/z/I/4/-/forthebirds.jpg" /></a>
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Please can you show us the code you are currently using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QktNN/   when the picture is hovered you can still see the edges blurred. I've even tried to decrease the width as well as the positioning of .one img but it's not doing anything

Comment: Please add some code in the post instead of just linking to a fiddle (although that is helpful as well). Besides from that, the example seems to have sharp edges using the overflow:hidden technique...?

Comment: darn it, yeah, this is tricky. good question.  I haven't found a css-only solution that's general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can clip any image with Javascript by

- Creating a `<canvas>` tag the of size of the clipped area
- Drawing the image inside canvas from the clipped source coordinates using `canvas.getContext().drawImage()`, also called slicing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#Slicing

Natureally Microsoft browsers with still active market share might need their own hocus pocus, Flash extension or whatever to make Redmond happy.

Also because you are obvious doing image filtering this might be great interest of you

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/